# Allow only enter keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a jQuery script to ignore the execution of the `keyup` or `keypress` event listener function and execute it only if I press the Enter key on the keyboard.

```
$(document).on("keypress", "input", function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode != 13) { 
    console.log('Not enter')
  } else {

  }
});
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, But where is the problem, just write code in else section

Comment: i want to ignore the execution of function for exemple : <input type="text" id="text" class="text" (keyup)="searchDataTable($event)" >  
i want to execute this function -> searchDataTable($event) only if I press enter

Answer (score 0):

Search for `event.preventDefault()` on the [jQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

```
$(document).on("keypress","input", function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode != 13) { 
        console.log('Not enter')
    } else {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action if not enter
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you pieter, I think you did not understand the problem: i want to ignore the execution of the function in lestener for exemple : <input type="text" id="text" class="text" (keyup)="searchDataTable($event)" > i want to execute this function -> searchDataTable($event) only if I press enter